# R Shiny and Spark: how to free Spark resources?

Tags: r, apache-spark, shiny, sparklyr

Say we have a **Shiny app** which is *deployed* on a Shiny Server. We expect that the app will be used several users via their web browser, as usual.

The Shiny app's `server.R` includes some `sparklyr` package code which connects to a Spark cluster for classic `filter`, `select`, `mutate`, and `arrange` operations on data located on HDFS.

**Is it mandatory to disconnect from Spark: to include a `spark_disconnect` at the end of the server.R code to free resources ?** I think we should never disconnect at let Spark handle the load for each arriving and leaving user. Can somebody please help me to confirm this ?

Comment: _"Spark provides a mechanism to dynamically adjust the resources your application occupies based on the workload ...  disabled by default ...  available on all coarse-grained cluster managers"_ (i.e. not in `local` mode) cf. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** `SparkSession` and `SparkContext` are not lightweight resources which can be started on demand.

Putting aside all security considerations related to starting Spark session directly from a user-facing application, maintaining `SparkSession` inside server (starting session on entry, stopping on exit) is simply not a viable option.

`server` function will be executed every time there is an upcoming event effectively restarting a whole Spark application, and rendering project unusable. And this only the tip of the iceberg. Since Spark reuses existing `sessions` (only one context is allowed for a single JVM), multiuser access could lead to random failures if reused session has been stopped from another `server` call.

One possible solution is to register [`onSessionEnded`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/onFlush.html) with `spark_disconnect`, but I am pretty sure it will be useful only in a single user environment.

Another possible approach is to use global connection, and wrap `runApp` with function calling `spark_disconnect_all` on exit:

```
runApp <- function() {
  shiny::runApp()
  on.exit({
    spark_disconnect_all()
  })
}
```

although in practice resource manager should free resources when driver disassociates, without stopping session explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, which means that I should NEVER include any Spark session- nor context-related connection with the Shiny server.R code. The code must re-use a session and a context that already exist. And of course, I should never stop/disconnect these. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The `SparkSession` lives in the Spark driver. But the executors may be provisioned and discarded auto-magically (unless they run in the same JVM as the driver i.e. in `local` mode) cf. `spark.dynamicAllocation.*` and `spark.shuffle.service.*` in http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter How dynamic allocation is relevant here? `spark_connect` and `spark_disconnect` manges driver and session.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Just to clarify: it's a real Spark cluster using YARN (no local mode neither stand-alone)

Comment: @zero323 > the question was _"how to free Spark resources"_ and IMHO the resources used by the executors count as "Spark resources"...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter you're right, maybe my question was misleading, maybe I don't need to free resources in this "Shiny app with users" scope since Spark handles dynamically the workload as users enter and leave. But still can you confirm that I have to put the `spark_connect` (which generates a context) inside or outside the `shinyServer(function(input, output, session)` function of the Shiny server.R file.