# Shiny and Spark: where to run spark_connect?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Following my [how to free Spark resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325625/r-shiny-and-spark-how-to-free-spark-resources) post, does it matter where you  place the (**sparklyr**) `spark_connect` in the server.R : within or outside the `shinyServer(function(input, output, session)` ?

Comment: the link doesn't work (https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/connection_spark_shinyapp.h/)

Comment: just try this: https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/connection_spark_shinyapp.html