# Is it possible to kill idle sparklyr sessions?

Tags: r, rstudio, sparklyr

Is it possible to kill idle `sparklyr` spark sessions after a given period of inactivity? I don't need to kill sessions that run long because they are processing a lot of data, but I need to terminate hanging sessions when user didn't call `spark_disconnect` having had finished doing their stuff.

Ideally a solution should be possible for `sparklyr` run from anywhere. However it would probably be ok if this could be accomplished within RStudio Server. Is it possible to define a callback function to be triggered when RStudio suspends a session per the `session-timeout-minutes` configuration (defined in `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf`)? If so it would be simple enough to test whether `sparklyr` is attached and, if so, execute `spark_disconnect_all()`.

Comment: Would something like https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/r/R/Tools.R#L464 do the trick? I think direct use of `.rs.*` is discouraged, but I'm just after a functional solution to prevent long-running idle spark sessions from consuming shared resources.

Comment: What about using `pool` package? In principle this could be used to build a pool of any connections. If the pool is destroyed, the connections are also destroyed and `gc` is called. Also, it has timeout functions as well.

Comment: Here is the answer on question like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325625/r-shiny-and-spark-how-to-free-spark-resources

Comment: Thanks. I need to look more closely at pool. Unfortunately I'm not using a shiny app, so using a shiny callback won't work.